# python subprocess Process crashes when dictionary size changes

Tags: python, dictionary, subprocess

***NOTE:*** The problem ultimately did not have anything to do with `subprocess`, it was just a simple dict modification while iterating.

I have a class `Agent` which has a `launch()` method that performs a bunch of operations - grabs data, writes logs, prints to console. This method takes a list of dictionaries with a bunch of parameters that control what it does, and it loops over this list of dicts doing similar work for each dictionary. ***Note:*** to start, `launch()` calls `subprocess.Popen` (once) to launch a terminal application that needs to be running for `launch()` to perform its work.

During `launch()`, each dict is modified - e.g., a key is added for tracking files that were created, another key is added with statistics for the work that `launch()` did on that dict's parameters, etc. When `launch()` has iterated through all the parameter dicts, I go back and loop through the dicts to save each to a `pickle` file for later.

My issue is that I am launching several `Agent` instances (each with their own list of parameter dicts) in parallel using `subprocess.Process`. ***Note:*** each calls its own `subprocess.Popen` with different cmdline args to the terminal app it opens. Everything works fine, they all create their logs (correctly saved to file), print their info to the console, grab their correct data. But, when the main loop of each individual `launch()` finishes and they try to loop over their respective parameter dicts, I get the following error for each `Process` instance (full traceback included in case it matters where it originates!):

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/--/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/--/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "../app/api.py", line 28, in spawn
    agent.launch(**kwargs)
  File "../app/agent.py", line 94, in launch
    self.subagent.launch(...)
  File "../app/subagent.py", line 445, in launch
    for param_dicts in self.finished+self.graveyard:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Any insight into why this is happening and advice on how to deal with this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing your code.

Comment: The work that `launch()` does is pretty long with many subclasses and submethods, but I'll try to add some abstracted version.

Comment: Maybe the issue has nothing to do with subprocesses, but simply you modified a dictionary while iterating it.

Comment: yep, I'm dumb, I was trying to delete some "temp" keys while iterating over the dict at the end. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says exactly what the problem is:

```
>>> d = {1: 2}
>>> for k in d:
...     d[3] = 2
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

To fix it, copy the keys if you have to modify the dictionary inside the loop (or if you have a background thread that might do it):

```
>>> for k in list(d):
...     d[4] = 3
... 
>>>
```

Modifying a dictionary in a separate process is ok. Processes work on copies of the data by default.